# Filter PHP Array Keys and calculating mean value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I have an array with dates as keys and prices as values. Like this:

```
Array
(
    [2016-11-11] => 25.05
    [2016-11-12] => 25.05
    [2016-11-13] => 25.05
    [2016-11-14] => 25.05
    ...
)
```

Now i need to calculate the mean value of today - 1 till today - 8. Of course it should also calculating correctly if there is less than 8 entries.

I'm thinking of extracting the keys and filter for the values and put that all in for loop. But i bet there will be a better way. I am at least happy for an idea in which direction to start with. May you help me?

The "today" i defined like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
$timestamp = time();         
$today = date("Y-m-d",$timestamp);
```

edit:
The output should be like

```
$last_week_mean = "value" of key[today-1] + "value" of key [today-2]

+ ... / count(amount of key values in this range)
```

But i don't know how to build this query/filter - thing :)

Comment: So what is the exact problem?

Comment: Can you provide the excepted output along with your query? @FabrizioCocco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` to get the specific date range you want. But after than, you don't need to use a loop to calculate the average. You can just use sum / count of the filtered array.

```
$d1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('8 days ago'));
$d2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1 day ago'));

$range = array_filter($your_array, function($date_string) use ($d1, $d2) {
    return $date_string >= $d1 && $date_string <= $d2;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$average = array_sum($range) / count($range);
```

---

Also, just in case you're getting your initial array from a database, it would most likely be easier and more efficient to only select the dates you want to begin with.

Comment: this was exactly what i'm was looking for. And yes: there is a db behind. I was pretty unsure which way would be better :) But for the moment i stay with your code. It works awesome.

Comment: @FabrizioCocco In the DB you can use `SELECT AVG(price) FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN ... AND ...`

Comment: @FabrizioCocco Barmar's suggestion will almost certainly perform better than this PHP approach. I'd really recommend looking into it.

Comment: thank you guys! It's allready late here. I will try it tomorrow! Once more! You both are awesome!